# How lack of information changes state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

Suppose two orthonormal states $|\psi_0\rangle$ and $|\psi_1\rangle$ are kept in two separate boxes. If we know which box shares which state, the state of the composite system is $|\psi_0\rangle |\psi_1\rangle$. But if this information is not available what is the state of the composite system ?

Comment: It is important to note that *your* lack of information never changes the actual state of the system (what does the electron care if you know where it is or not?), but it changes the best **description you may use** for the system. And then you will need density matrices.

Comment: Sorry if it is not clear. I am asking for that description.

Answer (score 5):

If you have incomplete information about your system, then you can no longer consider the system to be in a pure state, and you need to describe the resulting mixed state as a density matrix that's a [convex combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_combination) of the full-information states
$$
\rho_{01}=|\psi_0\rangle\langle\psi_0|\otimes|\psi_1\rangle\langle\psi_1|
$$
and
$$
\rho_{10}=|\psi_1\rangle\langle\psi_1|\otimes|\psi_0\rangle\langle\psi_0|.
$$
How you mix them will depend on how much information you have about where each state went, and if you really have no information at all then you should use the even-weights mixture
$$
\rho=\frac12\bigg(
|\psi_0\rangle\langle\psi_0|\otimes|\psi_1\rangle\langle\psi_1|
+
|\psi_1\rangle\langle\psi_1|\otimes|\psi_0\rangle\langle\psi_0|
\bigg).
$$
It's important to note, on the other hand, that this is rather different to coherent superpositions of the form $|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg( |\psi_0\rangle|\psi_1\rangle + |\psi_1\rangle |\psi_0\rangle \bigg)$, where the information isn't just unavailable - it just doesn't exist.

Comment: Some useful-looking comments have been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61312/discussion-on-answer-by-emilio-pisanty-how-lack-of-information-changes-state).